# Can you route Point-to-site traffic through Azure Firewall?

Tags: azure, vpn, firewall, azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn

It seems like there are a lot of traffic routing options when using Azure's Point-to-site VPN but I can't find any details on when you're connected through the Azure VPN client.  Can you, then, send that traffic out through the Azure Firewall egress point.  We don't use the default Azure Egress because we need our Azure traffic to come from a single IP (from the AFW)

Any ideas if you can route the traffic coming in from the Client VPN, out through the Azure Firewall?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a UDR on the gateway subnet with a route stating that if the destination IP is subnet range of your VM, next hop Virtual Appliance as Azure Firewall IP(Private IP).

So the traffic from your P2S client reaches VPN gateway, and will be forwarded to the Firewall.

You need to configure DNAT rules in your Azure Firewall to forward the packets to the correct destination.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Does this forward the clients though? Do the VPN clients go through the Gateway Subnet at all?

Comment: Is this possible if using a Virtual Hub P2S VPN and Firewall (i.e. a secured virtual hub)?